# Decryption with Aes not working in textfile

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

I am Learning C#, and are practicing with decryption and encryption.

I used the [Aes Class Example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes(v=vs.110).aspx), and the encryption is working great.

However, when i am trying to decrypt the textfile, nothing happens.

I figured i had done something wrong in the decryption function, so i tested with a string instead.

The decryption worked perfect with the string So i am wondering what i am doing wrong.

This is what my encryption and decryption looks like:

```
  //The encryption
  string path = @"C:\encrypt.txt"; 
  //The path where my .txt file is.
  string textfile = File.ReadAllText(path); 
  //Reading the text in the file and storing it in a string.
  byte[] ByteToEncrypt = EncryptStringToBytes(textfile, myAes.Key, myAes.IV); 
  //From The Aes class example
  string encrypted = ""; 
  //Creating a string to store the bytes in.
   for (int i = 0; i < ByteToEncrypt.Length; i++)
   {
   encrypted = encrypted + ByteToEncrypt[i]; 
   //Adding all the bytes from an array to string.
   }
   File.WriteAllText(path, encrypted, LATIN1); 
  //Writing the encrypted string to the .txtfile.

  //The decryption
   string decrypted = DecryptStringFromBytes(ByteToEncrypt, myAes.Key, myAes.IV); 
  //From the Aes class example.
   File.WriteAllText(path, Decrypted, LATIN1); 
 //Writing the decrypted string to textfile.
```

**I am posting the Aes class below for further information.**

```
 static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes(string plaintext, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        //Checking the arguments
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(plaintext))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plaintext");
        }
        else if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
        }
        else if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
        }
        byte[] encrypted;
        //Create an Aes object
        //With the specified key and IV
        using (Aes Aesalg = Aes.Create())
        {
            Aesalg.Key = Key;
            Aesalg.IV = IV;
            //Create a encryptor to perform the stream transform
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = Aesalg.CreateEncryptor(Aesalg.Key, Aesalg.IV);
            //Create the streams used for encryption
            using (MemoryStream msencrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msencrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        swEncrypt.Write(plaintext);
                    }
                    encrypted = msencrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
        return encrypted;
    }

    static string DecryptStringFromBytes(byte[] ciphertext, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        if (ciphertext == null || ciphertext.Length <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plaintext");
        }
        else if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        }
        else if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
        }
        string plaintext = null;

        using (Aes Aesalg = Aes.Create())
        {
            Aesalg.Key = Key;
            Aesalg.IV = IV;
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = Aesalg.CreateDecryptor(Aesalg.Key, Aesalg.IV);

            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(ciphertext))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {
                        plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return plaintext;
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you're decrypting the file immediately after encrypting it, so your file's final contents will be the same as its initial contents.  If that's not what you're observing then you need to clarify in your question what you mean by "nothing happens".  What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @RogerN When i am encrypting, i usually comment out the decryption part, and vice versa. This is just a test to see if i can make it work. It's not actually a real application yet.

Comment: Please create a SSCCE. Your question does not seem to be answerable in the current form.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just add bytes to a String. Byte can have any value between `00` and `FF` inclusive (using hexadecimal representation). You simply seem to add those bytes as integers to the string, as

```
encrypted = encrypted + ByteToEncrypt[i];
```

simply creates a String value such as `"0255"` for byte values `00` and `FF`. Of course, you will have an issue when you try and decrypt such a string, if only because the bytes are not separated anymore.

Instead, you should create a base 64 encoding of the ciphertext after encryption, and convert it back into bytes before decrypting. Or, as ntoskrnl suggests, you can of course just treat the ciphertext as binary all the way, if that's an option.

Comment: Note though that files *can* contain binary data, so it's not necessary to Base64 encode the ciphertext before writing it down. (But don't treat binary data as a string.)

Comment: Then, how do i write down the encrypted to my textfile?

Comment: Yes, but i am only using `encrypted` for Writing it down in the textfile. for the decryption i am using `BytesToEncrypt`